# javascript ElementById clarification

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

My input tag looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="kkk" value="dis" disabled="disabled"></input>
```

This is my JavaScript function

```
function get(){
    alert(document.getElementById("kkk").value);
}
```

Though I don't have id for the above tag value gets printed when using `getElementById`. Can any one explain me the behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you're using Internet Explorer, which uses `name` as well as `id` (in several versions); [more here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html). Microsoft even [documents this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28VS.85%29.aspx), but it's [out-of-spec behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) which is fixed in IE8 and above (in standards mode).

Answer (score 4):

You are experiencing error recovery / backwards compatibility features that appear in some browsers (related to a time when giving an element a name or an id created a global variable of the same name), particularly when a standards-mode triggering Doctype is missing. You should not depend on this.